# Search like datatable on ASP.NET gridview

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I've used DataTables in some of my ASP.NET projects before. Now i am making a simple project in ASP.NET with LINQ to SQL.
I want to perform global search same like DataTables(where in one single textbox,we can search multiple column values)in my ASP.NET GridView using LINQ
Do you have any suggestions or link to any tutorials?
 So far i have done this :

```
var query = from p in db.GatePass_LoginUsers
    where p.LoginID.StartsWith(txtsearch.Text)||  p.Username == txtsearch.Text ||Convert.ToInt32(p.Age).Equals(txtsearch.Text)
    select p;
datagrid.DataSource = query;
datagrid.DataBind();
```

the above query is performs the search for Age.
I have 5 more fields Like Address and City

Any help would be much appreciated.